# Abstracting out Strings in objective-c (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, localization

I am working on an iphone application and I am wondering what the correct practice is for abstracting out strings. I am used to creating a file with constant strings and referencing them in my application (such as urls, port numbers or even button labels). I am wondering if this is considered good practice in Obj-C and if so what the best way to do it is? Should I make a class with the strings? Or use the ".strings" file?

p.s I may be localizing my application at a later time. I havent looked into how to do it, but I figure abstracting out my strings is a good idea while i'm developping.

Thank you!
MGA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

generally, you interface with `NSBundle`. You use a string to read a localized version of the string (which is loaded from a localized strings file).

there are also some macros some people use to lighten the syntax, these are prefixed with `NSLocalizedString`. `NSLocalizedString` implementations use `NSBundle`.

imo, you should use string constants to identify the localized string you read (like you should with dictionaries and object keys).

you can declare your constants using this form (objc assumed):

```
extern NSString* const MONAppString_Download;
```

and define like so:

```
NSString* const MONAppString_Download = @"Download";
```

then access it using:

```
NSString * tableName = nil; // << using the default
NSString * localized =
  [[NSBundle mainBundle]
    localizedStringForKey:MONAppString_Download
     value:MONAppString_Download // << return the string using the default localization if not found
      table:tableName];
```

sometimes it helps to create wrapper functions to reduce the noise, especially when you use them in many places:

```
// @return what's set to the above variable named  'localized'.
NSString * MONLocalized_Download();
```

then you set up your strings files like a map, one for each localization you support.

so, whenever you need to read a string which is visible to the user, you use the above form. also consider that there are other resources to localize (nibs, images, pdfs, etc.) which you may bundle with your app. much of the work here is also abstracted by NSBundle, of CFBundle, if you prefer.

good luck

Comment: I have found <strong>localization has not increased revenue</strong>.  That's not a helpful answer, so here was what I did w.r.t localization:
I ended up writing custom Java programs to do these things:
1. Correct strings without NSLocalizedString macro surrounding
2.  Run the program that scans your source code for NSLocalizedString and poops out a .strings file
3. Pull out UI strings from XIB files and add those to the .strings file

5. Run another program to re-write XIB files based on a .strings translation

Comment: very cool. it's a pain to add localization after the fact, that would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks--Justin, how do you use localize XIBs, if at all?  Was there a tool I missed or are translators supposed to have Interface Builder?

Comment: personally, i build views programmatically most of the time. in Xc3: 1) create a XIB 2) select it in "Groups and Files" 3) "Get Info"/cmd+I 4) click "Make File Localizable" - this moves the xib to a localized dir and creates a meta reference for the resource. 5) click the meta resource reference and "Get Info" 6) "General->Add Localization". this creates a new XIB (yup, it's more or less copy and paste implementation). (cont)

Comment: the regular means to get the strings to the translators is to provide them with the strings files. once you have the nibs all set up, you can use `ibtool` to export/import the localized string files. in this case, they will not need IB or ibtool.